# How to have concept of some dynamic class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two Class A and B. Both have most property common, both have couple of different fields. Now using either of class based on some condition. Using their common property. I can not change schema of Using inheritance.

eg

```
public class A
{
    public string field1 { get; set; };
    public string field2 { get; set; };
    public string field3 { get; set; };
    public string field4 { get; set; };
    public string field5 { get; set; };
    public string field6 { get; set; };
    public string field7 { get; set; };
    public string field8 { get; set; };
    public string anotherA1 { get; set; };
    public string anotherA2 { get; set; };
}
public class B
{
    public string field1 { get; set; };
    public string field2 { get; set; };
    public string field3 { get; set; };
    public string field4 { get; set; };
    public string field5 { get; set; };
    public string field6 { get; set; };
    public string field7 { get; set; };
    public string field8 { get; set; };
    public string anotherB1 { get; set; };
    public string anotherB2 { get; set; };
}

A a = new A();
B b = new B();
dynamic d;

if(isDo)
   d= a;
else
   d= b;

string strField = d.field1;
string test = d.field3;
```

Please tell me to best way to achieve this.

Comment: You state you cannot use inheritance, but have you tried using an interface?

Comment: Why not create a common base class?

Comment: Because Class already there. I dont want to use any other concept as of nw.

Comment: "best way to achieve this" and "I dont want to use any other concept as of now" are completely incompatible statements. You need to choose whether to battle on with misapplying `dynamic` because you believe that it's to much of a pain to change, or to listen to the advice that you've clearly asked for...

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to know how to find the type of a given instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't modify the base classes you can create new child classes that implement a common interface. But you have to copy the property values in the constructor.

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new A(){ Name = "A" };
    var b = new B(){ Name = "B" };

    INameProvider provider = new BNext(b);  
    //...   
}

//original classes  
public class A{

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class B{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

//common interface
public interface INameProvider {
    string Name { get; set; }
}

//adapters
public class ANext : A, INameProvider 
{
    public ANext(A a)
    {
        this.Name = a.Name;     
    }
}

public class BNext : B, INameProvider 
{
    public BNext(B b)
    {
        this.Name = b.Name;
        this.Id = b.Id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to map from one type to another where the types are unrelated by inheritance, but have a number of commonly-named properties, you can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

You can use NuGet to add AutoMapper to a project. For your sample classes, you can then map from one to another like so:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    public class A
    {
        public string field1 { get; set; }
        public string field2 { get; set; }
        public string field3 { get; set; }
        public string field4 { get; set; }
        public string field5 { get; set; }
        public string field6 { get; set; }
        public string field7 { get; set; }
        public string field8 { get; set; }
        public string anotherA1 { get; set; }
        public string anotherA2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public string field1 { get; set; }
        public string field2 { get; set; }
        public string field3 { get; set; }
        public string field4 { get; set; }
        public string field5 { get; set; }
        public string field6 { get; set; }
        public string field7 { get; set; }
        public string field8 { get; set; }
        public string anotherB1 { get; set; }
        public string anotherB2 { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a = new A {field1 = "A1", field2 = "A2", field3 = "A3"};

            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>();
            B b = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<B>(a);  // Copies fields from a to b

            Console.WriteLine(b.field1); // Prints "A1"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've witnessed so many abuses of automapper that I would almost universally recommend that it's avoided, because lazy devs love to abuse it. C# ain't javascript, and using automapper to sidestep this in order to enable duck-typing looks very much like another abuse to me.

Comment: @spender I guess that would be an ecumenical matter. :) (We don't use it here, but for use only with DTOs when you cannot change the exisiting classes (as the OP says) it's probably not too horrendous.)

Comment: Definitely an ecumenical matter! [This](http://blog.alanta.nl/2015/04/automapper-is-evil.html) is an interesting read on the matter from a priest of automapper atheism.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn inheritance in OOP:

```
public class Common
{
    public string field1 { get; set; };
    public string field2 { get; set; };
    public string field3 { get; set; };
    public string field4 { get; set; };
    public string field5 { get; set; };
    public string field6 { get; set; };
    public string field7 { get; set; };
    public string field8 { get; set; };
}
public class A : Common
{
    public string anotherA1 { get; set; };
    public string anotherA2 { get; set; };
}
public class B : Common
{
    public string anotherB1 { get; set; };
    public string anotherB2 { get; set; };
}

A a = new A();
B b = new B();
Common d;

if(isDo)
   d= a;
else
   d= b;

string strField = d.field1;
string test = d.field3;
```

Comment: I have already class using LINQ(they may have different order as well), I dont wanna disturb them.

Comment: So you can define an interface instead of class

Answer (score 1):

If you can't modify the classes themselves, and you absolutely want to have a common interface, you'll need to write your own [Adapters](http://www.dofactory.com/net/adapter-design-pattern).

Comment: can you explain me with example how can I achieve in above exmple without class change

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is best solved by ditching `dynamic` altogether and using an interface.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string field1 { get; set; }
    string field2 { get; set; }
    string field3 { get; set; }
    //etc...
}

public class A : IFoo
{
    public string field1 { get; set; }
    public string field2 { get; set; }
    public string field3 { get; set; }
    //...etc
    public string anotherA1 { get; set; }
    public string anotherA2 { get; set; }
}

public class B : IFoo
{
    public string field1 { get; set; }
    public string field2 { get; set; }
    public string field3 { get; set; }
    //...etc
    public string anotherB1 { get; set; }
    public string anotherB2 { get; set; }
}
```

So now you can:

```
IFoo obj = isDo ? (IFoo)new A() :  (IFoo)new B();
string strField = d.field1;
string test = d.field3;
```

Comment: I can not move my field into interface, because in LINQ order of property is different.

Comment: @KaranGandhi Which "order of" property? What does that even mean?

Comment: In Linq Entity Framework it matter a lot, it decide rank of column in database.

Comment: @KaranGandhi What this suggests to me is that your question is incomplete, and that you are trying to solve a problem using a very specific technique that is probably incorrect. Can you state your ***actual*** problem, rather than the approach that you believe will solve it... If we understand the actual problem you are trying to solve, then you'll get a much better answer.

Comment: Problem is mention only, but I dont wanna make change to class A and B and achieve same.